# How do I implement different ToolbarItem for every new page without using custom renderer?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, cross-platform, toolbaritems

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Text ="Item 1"  
                Priority="0" Order="Primary" />
        <ToolbarItem Text ="Item 2"  
              Priority="1" Order="Secondary" />
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

I have a toolbar on the mainpage, from where I navigate to this secondary page. However I am not able to display the ToolbarItems on this secondary page.

Comment: how are you navigating to the 2nd page?  You should be able to display ToobarItems on any page that has a Toolbar (ie, is contained in a NavigationPage)

Comment: await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new ListDisplay(FN, FName, AT, Desc, FlowN, SN, ED, T)); this is my code behind of the main page, ListDisplay is my secondary page.

Comment: you are using a modal, so you need to wrap `ListDisplay` in a `NavigationPage`

Comment: And that just works perfectly! I thought modal had a property to change the ToolbarItem, but apparently it's a NavigationPage property. Thank you once again @Jason